# Link a domain to Amazon lightsail, ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, ubuntu-16.04, iptables, amazon-lightsail

I'm unable to ping domain name or amazon static ip from the lightsail instance (attached to that static ip)

1. Bought a domain name (say, test.com) from Google.
2. Created an Amazon Lightsail ubuntu 16.04 instance & attached a static IP
3. Enabled firewall on lightsail instance & allowed ports ssh/http/https
4. DNS settings added on google domain as below

> `Using google domain name servers`
>
> `Registered host: www.test.com -> Amazon static ip`
>
> `Custom resource records: @ -> A -> Amazon static ip`
>
> `Custom resource records: www -> A -> Amazon static ip`

After all the above steps, am able to access test.com from web-browser

**Now the issue is**, am unable to ping test.com from lightsail instance (the same created in step-2).
To add, am able to ping google.com from the same instance. I'm doubting if any route missed.

Can someone guide me here. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ping is uses the ICMP protocol, and the Lightsail firewall rules do not have a way to allow that protocol so that instances to be pinged from the Internet -- they only allow TCP and UDP.  All outbound traffic is allowed, and the firewall is stateful, so you can ping out but not in.

Comment: Hi Michael - sqlbot
Thank you for sharing the info.
Am wondering, how ping for google.com is successful, from the same instance.

Comment: You can ping **out** because the firewall is stateful -- it allows the reply because it remembers the request.

Comment: As of April 19, 2021, you can now select ICMP as the protocol in Lightsail firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

Even it is late, it might be useful for someone.
In lightsail just add new rule `Allow TCP+UDP 0-65535`.

Comment: You want to allow all ports?

Comment: I couldn't find another way yet.

Comment: You should explain what your answer does. Imagine someone copying this blindly in a production.

Comment: I would discourage this. As of April 19, 2021, you can now select ICMP as the protocol in Lightsail firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

As of April 19, 2021, the protocol options in Lightsail firewall rules now include:

- Ping (ICMP)
- Custom ICMP
- All ICMP

I have successfully got a Lightsail instance to respond to pings by selecting the first option, Ping (ICMP). No port selection is required. I recommend adding an IP restriction for enhanced security, if your use case allows.